# Blog loop in root breaks formatting/parsing - jekyll site

Tags: yaml, jekyll

I've made a jekyll site, and all was fine and dandy. Then I decided to move the blog to the root of the domain. Now it looks like jekyll doesn't parse my posts correctly. All formatting is stripped from the post content. Headers, highlighting and everything is just output as a string. Html tags from my layout files are intact, and everything else is working as expected.

This is my index.html which renders the blog loop:

```
---
layout: main
title: my title
---
{% for post in site.posts %}
<article>
    <h3><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h3>
<time datetime="{{ post.date | date: "%Y-%m-%d" }}"><span>{{ post.date |     date_to_string }}</span></time>
{{ post.content | postmorefilter: post.url, "Read the rest of this entry" }}
</article>
{% endfor %}
```

And this is the layout for my posts (journal.html):

```
---
layout: main
---

<article>
    <h2>{{page.title}}</h2>
    {{ page.content }}
</article>
```

My posts uses `layout: journal`

I have removed the gererated site, stopped and started jekyll and numerous other things.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, turns out it was my own fault as always.

My journal layout was wrong. I changed `{{ page.content }}` to `{{ content }}` - ét voila!